EXCEL VBA: Why is it not possible to call a UDF, which contains anywhere Application.Evaluate(), with Application.Evaluate()?
It took me some time to figure out that it is not possible use the Application.Evaluate() function with a user defined function which contains also Application.Evaluate(). See the code example below.
Public Sub main()
    Dim func$: func = "some_function()"
    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate(func)
End Sub


Public Function some_function() As Variant
    some_function = Application.Evaluate("0.0003")
End Function

This seems to be a VBA bug. However, I appreciate any idea how to handle this aside avoiding Application.Evaluate() within the code of the UDF. Thanks!

You should use Application.Run. Just remove the parenthensis when specifying the function name
Public Sub main()
    Const func = "some_function"
    Debug.Print Application.Run(func)
End Sub

Or, when used as UDF
Public function myUDF()
    Const func = "some_function"
    myUDF = Application.Run(func)
End Sub


Thanks, FunThomas, that works. Let me extend my question above, because this was a special case. What if my UDF requires input arguments, e.g., myUDF(arg1, ...) ?

Syntax: Application.Run (Macro, [Arg1, [Arg2, [Arg3, ....]]])

The Run method is a little bit tricky to use in case of two workbooks. There are many posts dealing with this I tried to summarize them with the essential parts.
In this demo there is a workbook (name Book2.xlsm) with the following codes:
In Sheet1 code pane:
Function sh1()

sh1 = "I am Sheet1"
Debug.Print sh1 & " on the sheet"

End Function

in Module1 module
Function md1()

md1 = "I am Module1"
Debug.Print md1 & " on the module"
End Function


Sub gen()  ' this is to test in the own workbook (Book2)

Debug.Print md1
Debug.Print Sheet1.sh1
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.tw1
End Sub

in ThisWorkbook code pane
Function tw1()

tw1 = "I am Thisworkbook"
Debug.Print tw1 & " on this workbook"
End Function

And in the caller workbook there is a code, in a Module (not essentially)
Important

The single quote is always needed, even if there is no space in the workbook name.
If the workbook is closed the program will open it.

Sub callotherworkbookfunction()


Debug.Print Application.Run("'c:\users\username\desktop\book2.xlsm'!module1.md1") & "in caller"
Debug.Print Application.Run("'c:\users\username\desktop\book2.xlsm'!sheet1.sh1") & "in caller"
Debug.Print Application.Run("'c:\users\username\desktop\book2.xlsm'!thisworkbook.tw1") & "in caller"


End Sub

If gen() method is run the result looks like this:
I am Module1 on the module
I am Module1
I am Sheet1 on the sheet
I am Sheet1
I am Thisworkbook on this workbook
I am Thisworkbook

so all the functions are executed and return a value.
If the Sub callotherworkbookfunction() is invoked the result looks like this:
I am Module1 on the module
I am Module1in caller
I am Sheet1 on the sheet
in caller
I am Thisworkbook on this workbook
in caller

so all functions are executed without error, but only the function in the Module returns value. The other two returns nothing and if assigned to a variable it will remain Empty.

If the UDF function is called as the text argument of the Evaluate method, it is evaluated twice. If the UDF itself contains an Evaluate call, the first time the result is correct, and the second time the result is an error value.
Therefore, if you want to indirectly call the UDF function from Evaluate, you should write it like this (based on the given example):
Public Sub main()
    Dim func$:  func = "new_function()"
    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate(func)
End Sub
Public Function new_function() As Variant
    Static v, flag
    If Not flag Then v = Application.Evaluate("0.0003")
    flag = False
    If TypeName(Application.Caller) = "Range" Then _
       flag = Application.Caller.Address = "$A$1"
    new_function = v
End Function

